# Returning multiple columns in one dplyr call

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:2, vectors = I(list(1:15, 4:20)))
```

and I want to add a few columns with the quantiles of each vector, can I do this using one line of code with maybe `do()` or some form of `mutate()`?

Comment: If you want to add a list as a column, perhaps `df1 <- bind_cols(df, df %>% rowwise() %>% do(qnt= quantile(.$vectors)))` or `df %>% mutate(qnt= lapply(vectors, quantile))`
  If you can show the expected format, it would be useful

Comment: i'm on the run but i'll cook something up later... in short, i want 0%, 25%, etc as columns, it seems like i can create a dataframe via `do()` then `bind_cols` it on?

Comment: I think `bind_cols(df, as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(df$vectors, quantile))))`

Answer (score 1):

One option is

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
          rowwise() %>%
          do(qnt= quantile(.$vectors))
bind_cols(df, as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, df1$qnt)))
#   id      vectors 0% 25% 50%  75% 100%
#1  1 1, 2, 3,....  1 4.5   8 11.5   15
#2  2 4, 5, 6,....  4 8.0  12 16.0   20
```

Or

```
bind_cols(df, df %>% 
                rowwise() %>%
                do(qnt= as.data.frame(t(quantile(.$vectors))))%>% 
                lapply(., bind_rows) %>%
               .$qnt)
```